# strange : setter defined in a different way

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate application I have seen setter for list are defined like below

```
public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees.clear();
        this.employees.addAll(employees);
    }
```

why not assign the list directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly it's necessary in your case. Can imagine the employees is not mutable. So assigning directly the list prevents adding more Employee objects. Instead of assigning the list all list members are added to originally mutable list.

Don't think it's hibernate related. Might be another logic.